# devbridge ajax autocomplete doesn't update suggestion list

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I am using devbridge ajax autocompletion script http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/. When I type something in the textfeild, the suggestion list does show up and the matched portion of the words are correctly highlighted. However, the problem is the list remains static. In other words, the suggestion list basically functions like a dropdown list. All the items (matched or not) remain on the list, and in the same order, no matter what you type in the text field.

Anybody can tell me what the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Anyone need code what you are using for this.

I will reply after understanding your code.

Sample Code :

```
$ (document). ready (function ()
{
    $('#searchresult').autocomplete(
    {
        serviceUrl: 'search.php',
        minChars: 1,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
        maxHeight: 400,
        zIndex: 9999,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
        // callback function:
        onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
        // local autosugest options:
        lookup: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'] //local lookup values
    });
});
```